# Choose donation sum field. The PHP code full of confusion :(

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

(Backend) I want to dynamically add and save the added values of donated sum into the mysql table named Donation campaigns.
(Frontend) User chooses a sum (SELECTed from db Campaigns) and INSERT it into certain field of db User Donations.
I'm really don't know what to do with the following. Pls help me for a thanks donation to solve the problem.

I. PHP FOR ADMIN

```
 <div>Choose your sum</div>
  <div id="camp_sum_list">
  <?php $camp_sum_num = attribute_escape($post["camp_sum_num"]);
  $camp_sums = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $camp_sum_num; $i++) {
    $sum_value = attribute_escape($post["camp_sum_" . $i]);
    if ($camp_sum_value != null && $sum_value != "") {
        $camp_sums[] = $camp_sum_value;
    }
  } ?>
  <?php $id = 0; ?>
  <?php foreach ($camp_sums as $camp_sum) : ?>
  <div id="camp_sum_<?php echo $id; ?>">
   <input type="text" class="sum_option" name="camp_sum_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $sum; ?>" /><a href="#" onClick="return removeFormTextField('camp_sum_list', 'camp_sum_<?php echo $id; ?>')">Remove</a>
  </div>
  <?php $id++; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="camp_sum_num" value="<?php echo count($camp_sums);?>" id="camp_sum_num"/>
   <div id="add-new-sum"><a class="button" href="#" onclick="return addFormTextField('camp_sum_num', 'camp_sum_list', 'camp_sum_', 'sum_option');">Add new</a></div>
</div>
```

II. PHP FOR CLIENT

```
        $output .='<p class="cont_sum"><label for="cont_sum">'.__('Choose your sum').'</label><select name="cont_sum">';
        $output .='<option value="'.__($CampRow->camp_sum_num).'">'.__($CampRow->camp_sum_num).'</option>';
        $output .='</select></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your current code, there is no database-connection or a SQL-query in there... so i made a simple form to submit a value to a database...

Submit a amount to a campaign, put this in file1.php

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database-name');
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO UserDonations (userID, campaignID, amount) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['userID']."', '".$_POST['campaign']."', '".$_POST['amount']."');";
    $result_insert = mysqli_query($db, $sql_insert);
}
else
{
    echo "
    <form method=\"POST\">
        <select name=\"campaign\">";

    $sql_campaigns = "SELECT * FROM Campaigns";
    $result_campaigns = mysqli_query($db, $sql_campaigns);
    while($row_campaigns = mysqli_fetch_object($result_campaigns))
    {
        echo "
            <option value=\"".$row_campaigns->campaignID."\">".$row_campaigns->name;
    }

    echo "
        </select>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\">
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Add funds\">
    </form>";
}
```

show a counter on the campaign site.. put this in file2.php (but in the end you should put this in your campaign-page)

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database-name');
$campaignID = "12";
$sql_current = "SELECT SUM(amount) total_amount FROM UserDonations WHERE campaignID = '".$campaignID."';";
$result_current = mysqli_query($db, $sql_current);
$row_current = mysqli_fetch_object($result_current);
echo "
<p>".$row_current->total_amount."</p>";
```